# install octave *no root*, missing BLAS and LAPACK

Tags: linux, octave, configure

I am trying to install octave on my machine (Scientific Linux 6.4 based on red hat) without having root access. After running the following:

```
./configure CPPFLAGS="-I/some_stuff/user_name/bin/pcre-8.32/include" LDFLAGS="-L/some_stuff/user_name/bin/pcre-8.32/lib"
```

(I had to install pcre apriori; before I got errors re: pcre), I get a message along the lines:

```
configure: error: You are required to have BLAS and LAPACK libraries
```

Now LAPACK has just been made in `$HOME/bin/lapack-3.4.2` yet the same error is still there. Also `$HOME/bin` is part of the path.

Any way to tell the configure tool for octave about this? (the obvious thing of adding another CPPFLAG/LDFLAG does not work). I'm assuming I'll encounter more such issues along the way, so any generic help/hint is greatly appreciated.

My level of linux is rudimentary to say the least, but I'm willing to work through it.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 1):

Does this site shed any light on the problem?   It describes the configuration options.

http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Installation.html

Comment: Not really. Here's a list to the "recommended" packages http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/External-Packages.html#External-Packages, but nowhere could I find how to tell configure where to look for the packages that are installed in my home directory.

Comment: @danb it's there. Look into the "Running conigure and make" section, which describes them. There's `--with-blas=<lib>` and `--with-lapack=<lib>`

Answer (score 0):

First, you should rather `./configure` all your software with some common prefix, such as `--prefix=$HOME/soft/`

<sup>Unless you know well what you are doing, I recommend against having different prefix for each installed software. You could add `$HOME/soft/bin` to your `$PATH`</sup>

And you should configure and build all the dependencies before configuring *octave* (and that includes *BLAS*, *LAPACK* and their dependencies).

Then, you want to pass specific configuration options, perhaps like `--with-blas=$HOME/soft`

<sup>I think you should pass the prefix used when configuring *BLAS*; you may want to run `./configure --help` first.</sup>

Read carefully each package's installation instructions. For Octave, they are [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Running-Configure-and-Make.html). Each package has their own.

<sup>Some software may require you to configure and build outside of their source tree!</sup>

Comment: where can I find a list of options like "--with-blas=..."? Also, when I install lapack, that takes care of blas as well, right? In any case, lapack has been installed beforehand (i.e., I ran make and it installed properly I'd guess since it ended with some testing routines that implied everything is ok).

Comment: As I edited in my answer: `./configure --help` should be useful.

Comment: Actually, I suggest rebuilding, in the *good order*, all the packages you need with the same `--prefix` to each `configure`. Good luck!

Comment: What throws me off is that some packages just need make. LAPACK for example does not have a configure file (hence I can't use the prefix trick). I just run make, and that's it. In retrospect, I'm not sure what configure does that make doesn't (or the other way around), but it seems configure creates the makefile (and then you run make).